# Starting to use JWT in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, authorization, middleware

I am trying to work with `JWT` in a `node.js` application.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbsmsi7l3r4).

But I am facing problems at the level of the middleware:

```
function authenticateToken(req, res, next)
```

which is at the timing 10:30 in the video.

When I run the code I always have:

```
authHeader == null
```

I have tried various things to find other possible forms for *req.headers['authorization']* like *req.headers.authorization* but to no avail.

I need to say that I have a route in my app that allows me to login and that I use right before using the route hitting the middleware. But in any case the *authHeader* keeps being *null*.

What should I do to make sure I get a valid authHeader as expected for the app to work as in the tutorial and move forward?

In case this may be useful, here is the complete code for the middleware function:

```
function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get the jwt access token from the request header.
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

  if (token == null) {
    console.log('authenticateToken-401')
    return res.sendStatus(401)
  }

  jwt.verify(token, 'myBigSecret', (err, user) => {
    console.log(err)
    if (err) {
      console.log('authenticateToken-403')
      return res.sendStatus(403)
    }

    req.user = user
    next()
  })
}
```

And also the code that is run when a user logs in:

```
app.post('/login', async function(req, res) {
  Parse.initialize(process.env.APP_ID);
  Parse.serverURL = process.env.SERVER_URL;
  Parse.User.logIn(req.body.usrname, req.body.password, {
    success: user => {
      // Let us handle this using JWT.
      const jwtUser = {name: req.body.usrname}
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(jwtUser, 'myBigSecret')
      res.setHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+accessToken);

      res.json({accessToken: accessToken})
    },
    error: (user, error) => {
      console.log('Error: '+error);
      res.render('pages/login.ejs', {});
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your ajax codes ?

Comment: I have no Ajax code. Let me know which part of the code you need to see please.

Comment: I mean your frontend code where your initialized your authorization

Comment: looks like you didn't set headers in ajax call

Comment: @Bibek
Since I try JWT for the first time, I am not totally sure of what you mean, but I added to my post the code handling the logging part; hoping this will answer your question.

Comment: @mirwaleed You may be right. How am I supposed to "set headers"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set headers in your request, looks like you didn't set headers in your request

Comment: I don't remember that I saw anything about setting headers in the tutorial, but I may have missed it somehow.

Comment: how're you supposed to get data from header without setting it

Answer (score 0):

On the login code above you have Signed using jwt so that it can be used when client app want to access some restrictable routes on your backend
Now whenever clients want to access route from frontend you need to set authorization token in ajax as header Something like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/apiyouwanttoaccess",
  method: "GET",
  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + Cookies.get("token") }
})
```

The above ajax code should be somewhere around js code where you want to access secure routes.
You have already signed token on your login(2nd code snippet) so it can be used within specific user by setting the cookies

Comment: I see, I am starting to understand how that precisely works. I am not yet sure where in my code I should store the cookies though.

Comment: Even though I changed my code and tried several variations. It is still not working. The first issue being that the headers I set (using res.setHeader) never seem to be reflected in the authenticateToken function. I haven't gone as far as setting cookies for now.

Comment: If I call the route with authenticateToken right after setting the headers, I should be able to make a test without cookie. Right? But even if this is possible I am not totally sure of how to call this route for the test to work.

Comment: for instance login is a button to call a secure route where you can make the ajax call keeping the headers and there might be other pages inside login you want to access which can be done the same

Comment: I understand what I need to do. See in my post "res.setHeader", inside "app.post('/login',...". But it does not work. That is the problem. And I am not using Ajax.